# Show images using viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using viewpager to show images from drawable folder
The images named:
a1
a2
a3...
To a700
So i use this code to get all images in viewpager

```
mImages=new int[700];
    for (int i = 0; i < 700; i++) {
        mImages[i] = getResources()
            .getIdentifier("a"+i, "drawable",     getPackageName());    }

            ImagePagerAdapter   adapter =     new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

It work fine and show all images
But when i use this code there is no first image in viewpager
The first image is appeared after first viewpager swip
Why?
How to start from a1 in viewpager

This is the adapter

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter         extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;
    }
    public int getImageId(int pos){return mImages[pos];}
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {


        Context context = MainActivity.this;
        final  TouchImageView imageView = new TouchImageView(context);



        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);



        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);

        return imageView;

}
```

And i use this cose in mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends    Activity {
 ViewPager  viewPager;
  public int[] mImages = new int[]{
R.drawable.startpic};
```

Comment: Start your loop with 1 to <=700

Comment: Not working i try that

Comment: @Vij Should be `< 700` for the `int[700]`

Comment: Why can't you use the `position` variable to get the resource in the adapter? Can we please see the adapter class?

Comment: Ok i will copy it

Comment: Swe my edited answer

Comment: See my edited question

Answer (score 0):

try

```
mImages=new int[700];
for (int i = 0; i < 700; i++) {
    mImages[i] = getResources()
        .getIdentifier("a"+ (i + 1), "drawable",     getPackageName());    }

        ImagePagerAdapter   adapter =     new ImagePagerAdapter();
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

you do not have an image named a0, so make sure you are not starting at a0. With the logic you have currently, I think you will also be missing a700 at the end (your for loop only goes to when i is 699).

Comment: do you see what i mean in the for loop tho? I mean I can't see the rest of your code so I'm not sure why images won't display, but if the code in your question is working and only skips the first image, the issue seems clear that it is because the i integer starts at 0 and you have files named from a1~a700.

Comment: Ok so i will try to name a pic to a0 and stop in 699 and tell u if work

Comment: noooooo thats not what i meant... lol must be something else if you can't see any photos. a1~a700 will work with the (i + 1) fix in my initial response

Comment: You loop `i` from `0 to 699` but your images are named as `a1 - a700` so you are trying to get first image with identifier `a0`! BUT you have `a1`!

Comment: first time if `i = 0` then `"a"+i` = "a0" use loop i from 1 to 700 -> like this: `i=1; i<=700; i++`

Comment: @StepanMaksymov if you loop from 1 to 700 then the array would still have an empty image at index 0, the best fix would be to use "a"+ (i+1) so that you are still filling the array from the beginning but using images a1~a700

Comment: why you think so? coder when he codes must think a bit - `mImages[i-1] =`

Comment: in anyway better way will be get image identifier in adapter to not get all 700 in one time )